# DOTNET Core: Unable to copy apphost.exe upon build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, build, permissions

I work on this project every day, and recently each day it refuses to build with the following error message:

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5100, 5): [MSB3021] Unable to copy file "D:\projects\Emulator\Emulator.Server\obj\Debug\net6.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net6.0\Emulator.Server.exe". Access to the path 'D:\projects\Emulator\Emulator.Server\bin\Debug\net6.0\Emulator.Server.exe' is denied.

I'm unsure what is causing this. I've tried everything I can think of: dotnet clean, deleting `bin` and `obj` folders, nothing seems to want to fix it.

The process is not running. I've also deleted the `.exe`, so it isn't in use anywhere.

Comment: does this happen after your reboot ? are the permissions to the folder or file ok ? for me this question is for superUser.com

Comment: Persists are logout and reboot. I believe the permissions are okayI can do everything else fine.

Comment: have you added that exe to any startup or automation task tha is launched as soon as you start the computer ? have you tried copying the source code to another folder and build it there ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Yes I've tried all of the above, I did say in my question I can delete the .exe so its clearly not being used by anything otherwise surely the OS level would kick in and stop me?

Comment: deleting an EXE does not mean deleting the EXE that is causing the problem, still this question does not belong on this site

Answer (score 1):

There really doesn't seem to be a fix other than renaming the folder to something else, building it, renaming it back. If you just change it on a regular basis it will keep happening and "break" the path its in when it breaks, no explanation I guess we just have to live with it.

It's a feature not a bug, right Microsoft?

Comment: changing the project folder name back and forth seems to work and the errors go away. This is only happening to me in VS2022 with .net6

Comment: just to mention. This can also happen in azure devops pipelines while building. Also it occured on netcore 3.1 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Turns out with running multiple screens I'd run the code and out-put to console. Then if I didn't close the console (cause busy, many files open which hid it etc) I'd make changes and then try and run and get the build error. Eventually figured out to close all console windows and it would run. Slightly different than your fault but sounds similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case it´s because I had two solutions opened, one at VS2019 and another with  VS2022. I my case was my first project with VS2022 (API project) and I needed restart machine and run VS2022 project before open other version of VS.
I hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, twice. In my case I had 2 distinct issues:

1. Antivirus was interfering: In this case, try to temporarily disable it and perform the build/run process again;
2. Application process was stuck: In this case you can check in the OS Process Manager. Search for the name {your_app_name}.exe in the list and kill the process. Then build/run again.